# Adding multiple views using LayoutInflator

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a 'favourites' view dynamically in android by recording whether the user has favoured a specific sound bite in my app and then inserting the sub view into a parent view with the appropriate info about a particular soundbite. Essentially, creating a custom playlist of soundbites.

I'm having problems with the layoutInflator though. If I add more than one sub view into my parent view, only the last sub view added will have the appropriate parameters entered, whereas the rest have the default values from the sub view xml layout.

Here is my java code displaying the general idea behind adding subviews:

```
LayoutInflater l = getLayoutInflater();
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.favlist);

if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
{
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Intent test = getIntent();

    if(test.hasExtra("favThunder")){
        String favValues = extras.getString("favThunder");

        View v = l.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, null);
        ll.addView(v);

        ImageView favImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favimage);
        favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.thundercats);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.favtitle);
        tv.setText(R.string.thundercats);

        TextView tvClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesplayed);
        tvClicks.setText("Times played: " + favValues);

        favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.thunder);
                mp.start();
            }
        });


    }

    if(test.hasExtra("favSkeletor")){
        String favValues = extras.getString("favSkeletor");

        View v = l.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, null);
        ll.addView(v);

        ImageView favImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.favimage);
        favImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.skeletor);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.favtitle);
        tv.setText(R.string.skeletor);

        TextView tvClicks = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timesplayed);
        tvClicks.setText("Times played: "+favValues);


        favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                }

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.skeletor);
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my sub view and parent view xml respectively

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/favimage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/thundercats"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/favtitle"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="A TEST TITLE"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:id="@+id/timesplayed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Times played: Heck!"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Parent xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.markohare.ohareb00716779_cw1.MainActivity"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/favlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my subview too complex or is there something wrong in my java code?

Thanks

Comment: You're calling `findViewById()` on the `Activity`, so it's going to return the first `View`s it finds with those IDs. Call it on the `View` you're inflating to get the child `View`s specific to that. E.g., `v.findViewById(...)`.

Comment: That worked a charm! Thank you very much!